# Make element own its own variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a function that lists out the months.

```
function genDate() {
        var d = new Date();

        var monthNames = [ "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
        "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" ];

        var day = d.getUTCDate().toString();
        var mon = d.getUTCMonth();
        var year = d.getUTCFullYear();

        $("#day").prepend('<span id="day_num">' + day + '</span>');

        var cc = mon;
        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            $("#date_cont").append('<div class="month"><a href="" 
                  onclick="return false;" >' + monthNames[cc] + '</a></div>');

            cc++;

            if ( cc > 11 ) {
                cc = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is have the generated .months elements hold different variables like its month index (0-11) that can be used by other functions. I guess the elements would act as objects (each element of .month class holds its own unique values). I'm new to javascript so I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add it to a data attribute, and get it later ?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var a   = $('<a />', {href: '#', text: monthNames[i] }),
        div = $('<div />', {'class': 'month', 'data-month': i });
                                              // ^^^^^ add a data attribute !
    $("#date_cont").append( div.append(a) );
}
```

and later you can do something like:

```
$('.month').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idx   = $(this).data('month'),
        month = monthNames[idx];

    alert( month );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DHGen/1/)

Comment: Thank you, this really helps. Question: why did you include e.preventDefault()?

Comment: @Andy - It's just good practice when clicking an anchor. Anchors shouldn't have an empty href, so usually a hash is used, but that scrolls the page to the top when clicked, and the preventDefault prevents that, or any other other default action when clicking the anchor. That last bit is just an example of how to get the data attribute from an element.

Comment: @adeneo You can always set the `href` to `href="javascript:;"` and avoid the `href="#"` issues you can run into (if you have to keep them anchor tags for some reason).

Comment: @Andy—if an A isn't a link or anchor, then a span or div should be used. That way there is no issue with the href value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery... if you have an element...

```
var elem = $('<div></div>');
elem.data('day', someValue); //sets 'day' to someValue's value
elem.click(function(e){
  var d = $(this).data('day');
});
```

NOTE: you can assign whatever properties you want (try not to conflict) on a dom element.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("mine");
elem.somePropertyName = someValue;
```

Also, data-* attributes are considered the appropriate way to push this into markup.

```
$('#elem').attr('data-day', someValue);
or
<div id="elem" data-day="someValue">...</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, what type does getElementById return?